Non-physicalist philosophers
I am looking for some major philosophers (of mind) who are critical of physicalism. I know the top guy, David Chalmers.
I have also read that belief in physicalism is really waning among younger philosophers. Would appreciate some testimony or examples here as well.

I don't know where you read that belief in physicalism is waning among younger philosophers, but physicalism has majority support among philosophers (not split by age, but I trust hard data from reputable places much more than I trust a stranger's "I read it somewhere"). I'd be surprised if there was a time in history where that is as popular as it is today.

Note that for many physicalists, as long as consciousness supervenes on the physical (i.e. depends on the physical), then consciousness is not seen as an argument against physicalism. Chalmer's main argument against physicalism is that there is no explanation for how, or why, certain physical processes result in consciousness. But even if one does not possess such explanation, or if one denies that there is an explanation in the first place, one can still be a physicalist, since the supervenience on the physical of consciousness may not depend on this.

Philip Goff has been quite vocal lately.
Frank Jackson, famous for the knowledge argument against physicalism.
Christian philosophers like Richard Swinburne and Alvin Plantinga...

Galen Strawson for his panpsychism "Consciousness and Its Place in Nature" (2006)?...
